# How can I replace many words in a string, using Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have a string I want to modify:

```
str = "I have several paints. For example, red, green, and blue."
```

I want to turn it into: `I have several paints. For example, XXX, XXX, and blue.`

So I have a list of words to replace with `XXX`:

```
colors = ["red", "green"]
```

I want to replace the colors from `colors` in `str`. Here's what I have so far:

- First, a function to replace something with "xxx": `subColor pat str = subRegex (mkRegex pat) str "xxx"`
- Next, I'm trying to map that or fold it over the list of colors. But I'm stuck: `map` just returns copies of the string, each with a single word replaced, and I've been getting errors with `foldl`. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I should also say that I will sometimes have multi-line words, so using `words` (as suggested in another similar question's answers) isn't really practical for me.

Edit2: I should add that one big regex pattern, like `blue|red` probably wouldn't work for me either, since I actually have several thousand of these things to replace.

Comment: Why does "several thousand things to replace" imply "one big regex pattern wouldn't work"?

Comment: Really really looks like a foldl(/foldr) type of problem. With your order of the arguments in subCOlot (pat before str) I guess foldr just fits? `foldr subColor str colors`

Answer (score 3):

What you want isn't `map` over several `pat`s and get a list of new `str`s, but apply `subColor pat` for each `pat` and combine these functions and apply it to `str`:

```
subColors :: [String] -> String -> String
subColors pats str = foldMap (Endo . subColor) pats str
```

In above code, the `foldMap` use the `instance Monoid (Endo a)`, which is same as `foldr (.) id`.

And, I still suggest you try the "one big regex pattern" solution, since a regex engine should do more optmization than you do, but that depends on the implementation of the regex engine, so if performance matters, you need to have a test first.

Comment: Why complicate it? Why not just `foldr subColor pats str`?

Comment: @JosephSible  You mean `foldr subColor str pats` ? That is a good idea !

Comment: Yep, I got them backwards. That's what I meant.